# django rest frame work : oscarapi authentication is not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-oscar

I am facing a weired issue when I call oscarapi calls through ios. It is working fine with POSTMAN. But when I call through xcode, it shows the following error.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Vary: Accept,Authorization,Cookie
Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 13:55:13 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Transfer-Encoding: Identity

{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

I sending the heading authrization as follows. This is working fine in postman.

```
 Authorization: Bearer iw7cGIz4uF036j7VbpGCXbceCCbbD1
```

My urls.py

```
url(r'^api/v1/categories', views.CategoryListCustom.as_view(), name='category-list')
```

views.py

```
class CategoryListCustomd(generics.ListAPIView):
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    return queryset
serializer_class = CustomCategorySerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, while inspecting the call log, I found that my call was 301 redirecting as follows -

```
"GET /api/v1/basket HTTP/1.1" 301 0
"GET /api/v1/basket/ HTTP/1.1" 200 401
```

and was returning an "Authentication credentials were not provided." error. 
Appending a "/" in url solved the issue.

The reason I suppose, 301 redirection not sending Authorization header in request. 
Hope this may help